# Points of circles

Tags: android

Here is my code that is to allow user to draw a circles onto a map in order to mark an area and later save it but I want to get the points for circle's line as in my picture because I want to save these points but I do not know what is the method to take circle's points .

```
public class Map extends  Activity implements OnMapClickListener{

final int RQS_GooglePlayServices = 1;
private GoogleMap myMap;

Circle myCircle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

 TabHost th = (TabHost) findViewById (R.id.tabhost);
 th.setup();

 TabSpec ts = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
 ts.setContent(R.id.tab2);
 ts.setIndicator("Draw Boundary");
 th.addTab(ts);

 ts = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
 ts.setContent(R.id.tab1);
 ts.setIndicator("Map");
 th.addTab(ts);

 ts = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
 ts.setContent(R.id.tab3);
 ts.setIndicator("Sign out");
 th.addTab(ts);

 FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
 MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
 myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();
 myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
 myMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 myMap.getCameraPosition();
}

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
 CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
 .center(point)   //set center
 .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
 .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
 .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
 .strokeWidth(5);

 myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

}
}
```

[image: drawing circles]

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012007/how-to-get-all-points-of-circle

Answer (score 0):

I think the single way is

```
private ArrayList<CircleOptions> points = new ArrayList<CircleOptions>

@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
 CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
 .center(point)   //set center
 .radius(500)   //set radius in meters
 .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)  //default
 .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
 .strokeWidth(5);

 myCircle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
 points.add(circleOptions);

}
```